# How to predict values from many R model in Power BI

Tags: r, machine-learning, powerbi, predict, machine-learning-model

I have many models, like:

```
iris2 <- data.frame(zzz= sample(c(0, 1),size =  length(iris$Sepal.Length), replace = TRUE), iris)
for (i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  saveRDS(glm(zzz ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data =  iris2[iris2$Species == i,]),
      file = paste0("model_", i))
}
```

I need to put these models inside power bi, for to run the predict function of R in power bi, But power bi doesn't accept list.

I was unsuccessful with the solution: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-predict-values-from-a-custom-r-model-in-power-bi-3364f83b0015

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **version = 2** to saveRDS() to ensure the correct processing in the Power BI web-version (currently R3.4.4). Afterwards the import in PowerBI should work as explained in the tutorial via:

Get Data -> r-script -> readRDS("your model.rds")

Additionally it is also possible to import your whole workspace into PowerBI, [see here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/saving-data-into-r-data-format-rds-and-rdata), yet models still need to be imported seperatly via readRDS()

Sources:

[orinigal tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-predict-values-from-a-custom-r-model-in-power-bi-3364f83b0015)

[similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704638/write-a-file-using-saverds-so-that-it-is-backwards-compatible-with-old-versi)

[PowerBI R version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-r-packages-support)